# If form multiple selects value are euals zero

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, select

I have multiple forms with one, two, three html select. I just want simple code if form select selected value equals to zero then console.log "please select order". Following is the script which I am working on.

```
$('form').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var dataitem = $(this).attr('data-item');

    if (dataitem == 1) {
        console.log(dataitem);
        var $myform = $(this),
            flavour1    =   $myform.find( "select[name='flavour1']" ).val(),
            drink   =   $myform.find( "select[name='drink']" ).val();
            console.log("Flavour :" + flavour1 + ", Drink :" + drink);
    } else if (dataitem == 2) {
        console.log(dataitem);
        var $myform = $(this),
            flavour1    =   $myform.find( "select[name='flavour1']" ).val(),
            flavour2    =   $myform.find( "select[name='flavour2']" ).val(),
            drink   =   $myform.find( "select[name='drink']" ).val();
            console.log("Flavour1 :" + flavour1 + ", Flavour2 :" + flavour2 + ", Drink :" + drink);
    } else {
        console.log(dataitem);
        var $myform = $(this),
            flavour1    =   $myform.find( "select[name='flavour1']" ).val(),
            flavour2    =   $myform.find( "select[name='flavour2']" ).val(),
            flavour3    =   $myform.find( "select[name='flavour3']" ).val(),
            drink   =   $myform.find( "select[name='drink']" ).val();
            console.log("Flavour1 :" + flavour1 + ", Flavour2 :" + flavour2 + ", Flavour3 :" + flavour3 + ", Drink :" + drink);
    }

});
```

please advice as i am stuck at this point of selection. If each select value == 0.
Thanks

Comment: Could you include the HTML? Also, what specifically is the problem? Are your log statements logging the `flavour` and `drink` that you expect?

Comment: I want to shrink my code with few lines. Is there any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usualy if you have multiple components similar you can use:

```
$myform.find("select")
```

This will give you all "select" elements in your form. And then you can find the value one by one using:

```
$myform.find("select").each(function(index, value){
     var valSelec = $(this).val();
     ///Make your if
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I create a function: `validateSelect()` that search on all selects of form and verify if the option selected was empty, if true they return false.

**Example:**

```js
$("form").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  if (validateSelect()) {
    console.log('All are filled valid');
  } else {
    console.log('Invalid');
  }

});

function validateSelect() {
  var fleg = true;
  $.each($('select option:selected'), function(key, val) {
    if (val.value.length < 1) {
      fleg = false;
    }
  });
  return fleg;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select name="number">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
  </select>
  <select name="letter">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```